# Access auto parameter's type within lambda

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, auto, decltype

I'm using a lambda function for boilerplate code:

```
auto import = [&](auto & value){
   // Do some stuff
};
```

As `value` is in fact a s`td::vector`, I need to access its `value_type` static member to call a template function on one of its element.

I tried use of `decltype` without success :

```
auto import = [&](auto & value){
   decltype(value)::value_type v;
};
```

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: `use of 'auto' in lambda parameter declaration only available with c++14`... please update your question tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `value` is an lvalue-reference, you can't get the member type from it and have to remove the reference part, e.g

```
typename std::decay_t<decltype(value)>::value_type v;
```

PS: You also need to add `typename` in advance (as [@Vlad answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61384618/3309790)) for the dependent type name. See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/3309790).

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zGxnpV51TDyxlDwb)

Comment: `typename` is also needed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, so we need to combine the two answers to get the correct solution..

Comment: Yes, typename std::decay_t<decltype(value)>::value_type works perfectly. Thanks.